# How to do a Post/Redirect/Get using Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

What's Sinatra's equivalent of Rails' `redirect_to` method? I need to follow a Post/Redirect/Get flow for a form submission whilst preserving the instance variables that are passed to my view. The instance variables are lost when using the `redirect` method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726884/can-you-specify-the-http-method-to-use-with-sinatras-redirect

Comment: You may want to take a look at Net::HTTP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184737/how-can-i-make-a-post-request-inside-ruby-sinatra

Answer (score 60):

Redirect in Sinatra is the most simple to use.

So the code below can explain:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  redirect "http://example.com"
end
```

You can also redirect to another path in your current application like this, though this sample will delete a method.

```
delete '/delete_post' do
  redirect '/list_posts'
end
```

A very common place where this redirect instruction is used is under Authentication

```
def authorize!
  redirect '/login' unless authorized?
end
```

You can see more samples under:

[Sinatra Manual](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/)

[FAQ](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html)

[Extensions](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html)

As for your second question, passing variables into views, it's possible like this:

```
get '/pizza/:id' do
  # makeing lots of pizza
  @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
  erb '%h1= @foo.name'
end
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I want to redirect within a handler and preserve the instance variables, like you can in Rails.

Comment: This also in Chrome generates a POST if you POSTed, so on refreshing the page you get form resubmission.

Comment: Sinatra Manual is no longer a valid link.

Answer (score 6):

The [Sinatra Book](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/) should clear your question. Especially the "[Redirect](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#redirect)" part.

Quoted from the book:

> The redirect actually sends back a Location header to the browser, and the browser makes a followup request to the location indicated. Since the browser makes that followup request, you can redirect to any page, in your application, or another site entirely.
>
> The flow of requests during a redirect is: Browser –> Server (redirect to ’/’) –> Browser (request ’/’) –> Server (result for ’/’)

Comment: The solution is to store things in the session. All the values you need after the redirect that are currently in ivars should be put in the session instead.

Comment: I recently asked a similar question, but have not yet found a definitive answer in case cookies are disabled on the client side...  Is what you suggest the only solution you know of ? Anyone else ? Thanks

Comment: The sinatra book link is no longer available.

Comment: Seems they have some hosting issues: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra-book/issues/71