# Can you specify the HTTP method to use with Sinatra's redirect?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have something like this:

```
post "/login" do

end

get "/login" do

end

post "/register" do
  ...
  redirect "/login" # I would like to redirect to get "/login" instead of post "login"
end
```

Can I tell sinatra that I want to use get, and not have it implicitly select "post" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most browsers will reset to GET with a 302 (default) redirect. If you're up against a browser that is actually doing the correct thing and NOT changing the request method, you can force it to change with a 303.

```
redirect '/login', 303
```

Source:
http://www.gittr.com/index.php/archive/details-of-sinatras-redirect-helper/

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work in Chrome, generates POST instead of GET.

Comment: I got this working. In my case, I had forgotten to add ```use Rack::MethodOverride``` to my config.ru