# How to make a POST request inside Sinatra code?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Clicking a button in a form will send a POST request to be handled by the following piece of code.

```
post '/register' do
   #send post request to http://www.randomsite.com
   #parse response
   #do something with it
   @user = User.first(:name => params['regUsername'])
   if @user == nil
     @user = User.create(
     :name         => params['regUsername'],
     :pass         => Password.create(params['regPassword']),
     :email        => params['regEmail'],
     :created_date => Time.now
     )
     redirect '/'
   else
     "User already exists."
   end
end
```

How can I send another POST request to a different website from within the Ruby code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Net::HTTP](https://github.com/augustl/net-http-cheat-sheet/blob/master/post_form.rb) from the Ruby Standard Library or the [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/basic.rb) gem.

Comment: How can I send multiple parameters along with the post request using Net::HTTP?

Comment: Be careful requesting from another site during processing for a client's request. If that second site has any delay your client will see it and blame your code, server or site. Rather than do it during the request try to do it ahead of time if at all possible and cache the result or store the metadata in a local database where it can be quickly returned to the caller. There are a number of [HTTP clients for Ruby](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients) that can be used for this.